# AJAX: if right click to open a new tab, render the whole page

Tags: ajax

I use AJAX on a link to insert data into a certain `<div>` in the same page. However, if the user right-clicks and opens in a new tab, the new page will contain only the data, without other page elements. How can I do to render a whole page for a right-click-new-tab?

HTML:

```
<a class=".updateContent" href="...">The link</a>
...
<div id="content></div>
```

AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('.updateContent').click(function() { 
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    $('#content').load(url); 
    return false; 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an href.  With an href the user has the option to open in a new tab/window or copy/paste no matter what you do (except maybe disable right click entirely but that's annoying).  I suggest something like the following:

```
<a class="updateContent" data-url="...">the link</a>
```

Then your jQuery

```
var url = $(this).data('url');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Matt. Although it works, but I don't want to disable the 'open a new tab' option. I'd like the user to have the option to see the whole page in a new tab/window. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, if you want to allow them to do that then the content that returns from the URL should have some script that detects a parent with the id of #content and if it doesn't find it it loads the rest of the template around itself.

Comment: Uh, ... How do I detect it on the server side?

Comment: Well, if you want to do that I can think of two different ways.  First is if the referrer will be a known value you can check that.  But if this can occur on any page in your system them you can append a query param when you call load(url) that tells you it's a partial.  If you see that query param return the partial, otherwise return the entire template.